# React not re-rendering components after using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-polyline

I am attempting to use React to build a website with a Google map that redraws the Polylines after I change the state. I am using setState() to set the state correctly, and I can see the values change when I print the object from this.state in the console but my Polylines on map do not re-render, and change color.

This is the main component that I am using for the project it includes a map and a table, renderMap() is what actually generates the map and update_congestion_lines is what changes the state and I am hoping to trigger a re-render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper, InfoWindow, Polyline} from 'google-maps-react';

class HomepageMap extends Component{
 static defaultProps = {
   center: {
       lat: 33.980530,
       lng: -117.377020
   },
   zoom: 11,
   style: {
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%'
   }
 };

 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     error: null,
     cctvs: [],
     cctv_objects: [],
     center: {
       lat: 33.980530,
       lng: -117.377020
     },
     style: {
       width: '100%',
       height: '100%'
     },
     zoom: 11,
     showingInfoWindow : false,
     selectedPlace: {},
     activeMarker: {},
     image_path : [],
   };
   this.update_congestion_lines = this.update_congestion_lines.bind(this);
   this.grabColor = this.grabColor.bind(this);
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   var url = "http://highwayanalytics.us/api/cctv?format=json&county=Riverside,San+Bernardino";
   fetch(url)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(
   (result) => {
       var list = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
           var cctv = result[i];
           if(cctv.image_url !== "Not Reported"){
           list.push(cctv);
           }
       }
       this.setState({
           cctvs: list,
           error: false
       });
   },
   (error) => {
       //console.log(error);
       this.setState({
           cctvs: [],
           error: true
       })
   });

   url = "http://highwayanalytics.us/api/graph?format=json&county=Riverside,San+Bernardino";
   fetch(url)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(
   (result) => {
     var list = [];
     for(var key in result){
       if(result.hasOwnProperty(key)){
         var val = result[key];
         var i = 0;
         if(key === "SR-60" || key === "I-10" || key === "SR-91" || key === "I-210"){
           for(i=0;i < val.length;i++){
             var prev_cctv = null;
             if(i!== 0){
               prev_cctv=val[i-1];
             }
             var next_cctv = null;
             if(i !== (val.length-1)){
               next_cctv = val[i+1];
               //Calc distance
               var prev_lat_midpoint = null;
               var prev_long_midpoint = null;
               var next_lat_midpoint = null;
               var next_long_midpoint = null;
               var temp = null;
               if(prev_cctv !== null){
                 if(prev_cctv.latitude > val[i].latitude){
                     temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                     prev_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                     temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                     prev_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude - temp;
                 }
                 if(prev_cctv.longitude > val[i].longitude){
                    temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                    prev_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                    temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                    prev_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude - temp;
                 }
               }
               if(next_cctv !== null){
                 if(next_cctv.latitude > val[i].latitude){
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                   next_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                   next_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude - temp;
                 }
                 if(next_cctv.longitude > val[i].longitude){
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                   next_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                   next_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude - temp;
                 }
               }
               var object = {
                   "cctv": val[i],
                   "cctv_id":val[i].cctv_id,
                   "prev_cctv": prev_cctv,
                   "next_cctv": next_cctv,
                   "prev_lat_midpoint": prev_lat_midpoint,
                   "prev_long_midpoint": prev_long_midpoint,
                   "next_lat_midpoint": next_lat_midpoint,
                   "next_long_midpoint": next_long_midpoint,
                   "car_count": null
               }
               list.push(object);
             }
           }
         }
         else if( key === "I-15" || key === "I-215"){
           for(i=0;i < val.length;i++){
             var prev_cctv = null;https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
             if(i!== 0){
               prev_cctv=val[i-1];
             }
             var next_cctv = null;
             if(i !== (val.length-1)){
               next_cctv = val[i+1];
               //Calc distance
               var prev_lat_midpoint = null;
               var prev_long_midpoint = null;
               var next_lat_midpoint = null;
               var next_long_midpoint = null;
               var temp = null;
               if(prev_cctv !== null){
                 if(prev_cctv.latitude > val[i].latitude){
                     temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                     prev_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                     temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                     prev_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude - temp;
                 }
                 if(prev_cctv.longitude > val[i].longitude){
                    temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                    prev_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                    temp = Math.abs(prev_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                    prev_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude - temp;
                 }
               }
               if(next_cctv !== null){
                 if(next_cctv.latitude > val[i].latitude){
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                   next_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.latitude-val[i].latitude)/2;
                   next_lat_midpoint = val[i].latitude - temp;
                 }
                 if(next_cctv.longitude > val[i].longitude){
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                   next_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude + temp;
                 }
                 else{
                   temp = Math.abs(next_cctv.longitude-val[i].longitude)/2;
                   next_long_midpoint = val[i].longitude - temp;
                 }
               }
               object = {
                   "cctv": val[i],
                   "cctv_id": val[i].cctv_id,
                   "prev_cctv": prev_cctv,
                   "next_cctv": next_cctv,
                   "prev_lat_midpoint": prev_lat_midpoint,
                   "prev_long_midpoint": prev_long_midpoint,
                   "next_lat_midpoint": next_lat_midpoint,
                   "next_long_midpoint": next_long_midpoint,
                   "car_count": null
               }
               list.push(object);
             }
           }
         }
         else{
           continue;
         }
       }
     }
       this.setState({
         cctv_objects: list,
         error: false
     });
   },
   (error) => {
       //console.log(error);
       this.setState({
         cctvs: [],
           error: true
       })
   });
 //Used for updating congestion lines, every 10 seconds
   // this.intervalID = setInterval(
   //   ()=> this.update_congestion_lines(),
   //   10000
   // );

 }

 componentWillUnmount(){
   clearInterval(this.intervalID);
 }
 update_congestion_lines(){
   //Update Congestions Lines
   console.log("Updating Congestion lines");
   var cctv_objects_dup = Array.from(this.state.cctv_objects);
   //Go through all cameras
   for(var i = 0; i < cctv_objects_dup.length;i++){
     var target_url = "http://highwayanalytics.us/api/vehicle/?cctv="+cctv_objects_dup[i].cctv_id+"&format=json";
     var target_photo_id = null;
     if(cctv_objects_dup[i].cctv_id !== undefined){
       fetch(target_url)
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(
           (result) => {
             if(result !== undefined){
               if(result.results !== undefined){
                 if(result.results[0] !== undefined){
                   //Find most recent photo id on specific camera
                   target_photo_id = result.results[0].photo;
                   target_url = "http://highwayanalytics.us/api/vehicle/?photo="+target_photo_id+"&format=json";
                   fetch(target_url)
                   .then( res => res.json())
                   .then(
                     (result) => {
                       //assign that camera the result of photo count
                         for(let index = 0; index < cctv_objects_dup.length; index++){
                           if(cctv_objects_dup[index] === undefined){
                             console.log("undefined");
                             continue;
                           }
                           if(cctv_objects_dup[index].cctv_id === result.results[0].cctv){
                             cctv_objects_dup[index].car_count = result.count;
                             break;
                           }
                         }
                     },
                     (error) =>{
                       console.log("Error with using target_photo_id");
                     }
                   );
                 }
               }
             }
           },
           (error) => {
             console.log("Error updating Congestion");
           }
         );
     }
   }
   //update cctv objects with new car counts
   this.setState({
     cctv_objects: cctv_objects_dup
   });
   //console.log("Lines Done Updating",this.state.cctv_objects[0].car_count);
   //console.log("here is cctv_objects",this.state.cctv_objects);
 }
 onMarkerClick = (props, marker) => {
   var latest_image = "http://highwayanalytics.us/api/search/?search=" + props.name;
   var path = [];

   fetch(latest_image)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(
       (result) => {
         //console.log(result.results[0].file_name)
         path.push(result.results[0].file_name)

         this.setState({
           activeMarker: marker,
           selectedPlace: props,
           showingInfoWindow: true,
           image_path : path,
         });
       }
     )
 };

 onMouseoverMarker= (props, marker, e) => {
   // this.setState({
   //   activeMarker: marker,
   //   selectedPlace: props,
   //   showingInfoWindow: true
   // })
   // console.log(this.state.showingInfoWindow)
 };

 onMouseoutMarker= (props, marker, e) => {
   // this.setState({
   //   activeMarker: null,
   //   showingInfoWindow: false
   // })
   // console.log(this.state.showingInfoWindow)
 };

 onInfoWindowClose = () =>
   this.setState({
     activeMarker: null,
     showingInfoWindow: false
   });

 onMapClicked = () => {
   if (this.state.showingInfoWindow){
     this.setState({
       activeMarker: null,
       showingInfoWindow: false,
       image_path: null,
     })
     console.log(this.state.showingInfoWindow)
   }
 };

 grabColor = (car_count) =>{
   console.log("Car Count", car_count);
   if(car_count === null){
     return 'green';
   }
   else{
     return 'red';
   }
 }
 renderMap(){
   var icon_image = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/camera_icon2.png';

   var cctvs = this.state.cctvs.map(
     (d) =>
       <Marker
         icon={icon_image}
         name = {d.id}
         onClick = {this.onMarkerClick}
         onMouseover={this.onMouseoverMarker}
         onMouseout={this.onMouseoutMarker}
         position = { {lat: d.latitude, lng: d.longitude} }
         lat = {d.latitude}
         long = {d.longitude}
         image_url = {d.image_url}
         route = {d.route}
       />
   );
   var prev_congestion_lines = this.state.cctv_objects.map(
     (object)=>(
       //prev_polyline
           <Polyline
             key= {object.cctv.latitude.toString() + object.cctv.longitude.toString()}
             path={[
               { lat: object.prev_lat_midpoint, lng: object.prev_long_midpoint},
               { lat: object.cctv.latitude, lng: object.cctv.longitude},
             ]}
             options={{
             strokeColor: this.grabColor(object.car_count),
             strokeOpacity: 0.75,
             strokeWeight: 10,
             icons: [{
               offset: '0',
               repeat: '10px'}],
             }}
           />
     )
   );
   var next_congestion_lines = this.state.cctv_objects.map(
     (object)=>(
       //prev_polyline
           <Polyline
             key = {object.cctv_id.toString() + object.cctv.latitude.toString() + object.cctv.longitude.toString()}
             path={[
               { lat: object.cctv.latitude, lng: object.cctv.longitude},
               { lat: object.next_lat_midpoint, lng: object.next_long_midpoint},
             ]}
             options={{
             strokeColor: this.grabColor(object.car_count),
             strokeOpacity: 0.75,
             strokeWeight: 10,
             icons: [{
               offset: '0',
               repeat: '10px'}],
             }}
           />
     )
   );
   return (
     <div style={{ height: '92vh', width: '100%' }}>
       <Map
         google={this.props.google}
         zoom={this.props.zoom}
         style={this.props.style}
         initialCenter={this.props.center}
         onClick={this.onMapClicked}
       >
         {cctvs}
         {prev_congestion_lines}
         {next_congestion_lines}
       </Map>
     </div>
   );
 }

 renderTable(){
   var content = []

   var path = "http://highwayanalytics.us/image/" + this.state.image_path;

   if (this.state.showingInfoWindow !== false) {
     content.push(
       <div className="row" style={{'padding': '35px'}}>
         <h2> Marker Information</h2>
         <img
           src = {path}
           style={{
             width: '380px'
           }}
         />
         <div>
           <span> Lat : {this.state.selectedPlace.lat} Long: {this.state.selectedPlace.long}</span>
           <p> Route : {this.state.selectedPlace.route} Marker_Id : {this.state.selectedPlace.name}</p>
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }else{
     content.push(
       <div className="row" style={{'padding': '35px'}}>
         <h2> Marker Information</h2>
       </div>
     );
   }
   return content;
 }

 handleClick(){
   this.update_congestion_lines();
   console.log(this.state.cctv_objects);
   this.forceUpdate();
 }
 render(){
   var map = this.renderMap();
   var table = this.renderTable();
   return(
     <div className="row">
       <div className="col-9">
         {map}
       </div>
       <div className="col-3">
         {table}
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Update Congestion Lines</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
 apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_KEY
})(HomepageMap);
```

renderMap() takes care of generating the map, markers, and the polylines. The color of the polyline should change based on the car_count. As you can see am logging the car count,the car count should be null initially but is not null after the state is set, even though console.log tells me the car_count is not null, the color of the line does not change.

```
 grabColor = (car_count) =>{
    console.log("Car Count", car_count);
    if(car_count === null){
      return 'green';
    }
    else{
      return 'red';
    }
  }
  renderMap(){
    var icon_image = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/camera_icon2.png';

    var cctvs = this.state.cctvs.map(
      (d) =>
        <Marker
          icon={icon_image}
          name = {d.id}
          onClick = {this.onMarkerClick}
          onMouseover={this.onMouseoverMarker}
          onMouseout={this.onMouseoutMarker}
          position = { {lat: d.latitude, lng: d.longitude} }
          lat = {d.latitude}
          long = {d.longitude}
          image_url = {d.image_url}
          route = {d.route}
        />
    );
    var prev_congestion_lines = this.state.cctv_objects.map(
      (object)=>(
        //prev_polyline
            <Polyline
              key= {object.cctv.latitude.toString() + object.cctv.longitude.toString()}
              path={[
                { lat: object.prev_lat_midpoint, lng: object.prev_long_midpoint},
                { lat: object.cctv.latitude, lng: object.cctv.longitude},
              ]}
              options={{
              strokeColor: this.grabColor(object.car_count),
              strokeOpacity: 0.75,
              strokeWeight: 10,
              icons: [{
                offset: '0',
                repeat: '10px'}],
              }}
            />
      )
    );
    var next_congestion_lines = this.state.cctv_objects.map(
      (object)=>(
            <Polyline
              key = {object.cctv_id.toString() + object.cctv.latitude.toString() + object.cctv.longitude.toString()}
              path={[
                { lat: object.cctv.latitude, lng: object.cctv.longitude},
                { lat: object.next_lat_midpoint, lng: object.next_long_midpoint},
              ]}
              options={{
              strokeColor: this.grabColor(object.car_count),
              strokeOpacity: 0.75,
              strokeWeight: 10,
              icons: [{
                offset: '0',
                repeat: '10px'}],
              }}
            />
      )
    );
```

[Here is what I get on the console and what the map looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WJme.png)

If anyone has an explanation of why the polylines are not being re-rendered after the car_count changes, I would be extremely grateful.

Edit: I have added to rest of the function of the first code block, and added a key to the next_congestion line as noted in the comments.

Comment: Fromm what library does the `Polyline` component come from? Can you create a live example that we can test?

Comment: You missed out part of your code (the part returning something from the function). Also I think it's cleaner (and potentially more performant) to split map and table into seperate components

Comment: Also note that your `next_congestion_lines` array does not have `keys` for each `Polyline`.

Comment: You *say* you're calling setState, but you don't show us where or how.

Comment: I have added the whole file to show where I am setting the state, I am setting it in the update_congestion_lines function. Sorry.

Comment: check if `render` [and `renderMap`] is called after change ... pass `car_count` as prop to `<Map/>` to have changing prop (... but children prop changes) ... move outer `div` from `renderMap` to `render`  ... create live example, it's hard to help without that